# Nopcommerce 4.0 301 Redirect Product Urls

Tags: nopcommerce

We're in the process of migrating from AspDotNetStorefront to NopCommerce v4.00. The product urls in AspDotNetStorefront are formatted like p-4321-product-se-name.aspx. We are wanting to move forward with a url structure like www.yourstore.com/SEName. I've looked at BackwardCompatibility1XRouteProvider and BackwardCompatibility1XController.cs.

In BackwardCompatibility1XRouteProvider i've added the following

```
            //products-old-aspdnsf
        routeBuilder.MapRoute("", "store/p-{id}-{SeName}.aspx",
           new { controller = "BackwardCompatibility1X", action = "RedirectProduct" });
```

This is working for 301 redirecting some products, but not for others. I've looked to make sure that there is matching entityid's in the urlrecord table...

Anyone have suggestions as to if I am doing this correctly?